# Change from qwerty to azerty in command line

Tags: command-line, keyboard

I start my command line in Ubuntu but if I type anything my keyboard is in qwerty. I want to change it to azerty. Is there a command that I can use to change it? If I go to the GUI of ubuntu, my keyboard is correct (azerty).

Thanks

Comment: When exactly do you get azerty? Already at the login or only after login? Also, what type of keyboard do you use? (I personally have a case with the Logitech K350, which can not be set to another layout in advance with the Xorg configuration)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This should set your keyboard to `azerty` in a terminal emulator:

```
setxkbmap fr
```

If on a console, that would be (as root):

```
loadkeys fr
```

Comment: Sorry, I have try your commands but it don't work... It's my first time that I work whit Ubuntu for school.

Comment: Please elaborate the "don't work" part. Is there an error message ? Clarify too in what context this is happening. Is it the GRUB menu ? The text console login ? the graphical Login window ? Something else ??

Comment: Kinda obvious, but use `setxkbmap be` or `loadkeys be`if you want to load the [Belgian AZERTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY#Differences_between_the_Belgian_and_French_layouts_of_the_AZERTY_keyboard) layout.

Comment: @BioGeek C'est vrai, les Belges ont aussi ces claviers azerty que le monde entier nous envie ;-)

Comment: Thanks ! in case loadkeys doesn't work (file not found), simply run ``sudo apt-get install console-data

Answer (score 2):

I tried what @jlliagre suggests but the OS told me "the permission is denied" so the solution here is very easy. If you are on the console you write `sudo loadkeys fr` to change the keyboard mode to azerty, then you enter your session password and finally all will be right.